# JSON response to shapefile

Tags: shapefile, python-2.7, json

I'm collecting road accidents from an API through a Python request and getting my response as JSON. The JSON response contains coordinates and general information as below.

```
{u'RESPONSE': {u'RESULT': [{u'Situation': [{u'Deviation':
[{u'Geometry': {u'WGS84': u'POINT (16.109539 60.9519234)'},
u'MessageCode': u'Tj\xe4lskada', u'IconId': u'frostDamage',
u'RoadNumber': u'V\xe4g 877', u'LocationDescriptor': u'V\xe4g 877 i
Falu kommun i Dalarnas l\xe4n.'}, {u'Geometry': {u'WGS84': u'POINT
(16.109539 60.9519234)'}, u'MessageCode': u'Viktbegr\xe4nsning
g\xe4ller', u'IconId': u'trafficMessage', u'RoadNumber': u'V\xe4g
877'}], u'PublicationTime': u'2019-03-13T19:45:25'}]}]}}
```

What I want to do is to create a shapefile with the coordinates I have in my JSON response in Python. Any tips?

Comment: While it's not particularly difficult to write a shapefile with pure Python, it's also unnecessary, since so many libraries support the format. Please choose a library and [Edit] the Question to include your coding attempt and a description of the problem you are encountering.

Comment: @Vince Okey, do you have a suggestion on a library?

Comment: just read the json format in python > https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp

Comment: I recommend pyshp to create a shapefile, https://github.com/GeospatialPython/pyshp